# Endless Scroll + Ordering

Tags: templating

Currently I have infinite scroll setup as below, but when changing the ordering of the entries, then loading more through the infinite scroll it's not loading in the order of the entries.

**Set Sort Options**

```
    {% set sortOptions = [
        {
            label: 'Name Z - A',
            value: 'title desc'
        },
        {
            label: 'Name A - Z',
            value: 'title asc'
        },
    ] %}

{% set selectedSortOption = craft.request.getParam('order', 'title asc') %}
```

**Pagination Loop**

```
{% paginate craft.categories.group('university').order(selectedSortOption).limit(1) as pageEntries %}
    <div id="university-widget-wrapper">

    {% for category in pageEntries %}
      <a class="university-widget w-inline-block" href="{{ category.url }}">
        <div class="university-widget-image"></div>
        <div class="university-widget-content">
          {% for asset in category.universityLogo %}
            <img class="university-widget-logo" src="{{ asset.url }}" height="40">
          {% endfor %}
          <p class="small-paragraph">{{ category.description }}</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>


    <div id="pagination">
      {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
          <a class="button left previous" href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}?q={{ selectedSortOption }}">Previous</a>
      {% endif %}
      {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
          <a class="button right next" href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}?q={{ selectedSortOption }}">Next</a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    {% endpaginate %}
```

**Javascript Adding Query**

```
{% set orderJs %}
  $(function(){

    $('#sortQuery').on("change", function(e){

     // Get the value from the select
     var filter = $(this).val();
     document.location.href = '{{ craft.request.getUrl() }}?order=' + filter;

   });

  });
{% endset %}
{% includeJs orderJs %}
```

**Endless Scroll jQuery**

```
<script>
  var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  '#university-widget-wrapper',
    item:       '.university-widget',
    pagination: '#pagination',
    next:       '.next'
  });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());            // shows a spinner (a.k.a. loader)
  ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({
    offset: 1,
    text: '<a class="button-positive w-button" href="#">Load More Results</a>'
  })); // shows a trigger after page 3
  ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
    text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'      // override text when no pages left
  }));

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `q` instead of `order` for the query param in the pagination URLs.